# how do I go about ensuring that the recently generated id is returned when we insert a record via a PostgreSQL View's trigger's function?

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, sql-insert, identity-column

Here is info about our technical development environment :

PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Here are the various code snippets associated with the various database objects in my PostgreSQL database:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.movies (
>
> id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 )
>
>                       , name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
>
>                       , director text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
>
>                       , cost integer NOT NULL
>
>                       , revenue integer NOT NULL );
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.vw_movies_info AS SELECT m_table.id,
>
>     m_table.name,
>
>     m_table.director,
>
>     m_table.cost,
>
>     m_table.revenue , 
>
>    FROM movies m_table;
> ```

> ```
>   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iud_vw_movies_info_func() RETURNS TRIGGER
>
>  AS $$ BEGIN
>
> IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
>     raise notice 'INSERT trigger, NEW = [%]', NEW;
>             Insert into movies(
>                       , name
>                       , director
>                       , cost
>                       , revenue)
>                Values( NEW.name
>                         , NEW.director
>                       , NEW.cost
>                       , NEW.revenue );
>                       
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
> ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' then 
>     raise notice 'UPDATE trigger, OLD = [%], NEW = [%]', OLD, NEW;
>                             Update movies ee
>                                    Set name = NEW.name
>                                                   where ee.id = NEW.id;
> ELSE
>     raise notice 'DELETE trigger, OLD = [%]', OLD;
>                             Delete from movies ee 
>                                       where ee.id = OLD.id;
> END IF;
> RETURN COALESCE(NEW,OLD); END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER vw_movies_info_trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT OR
>  UPDATE OR DELETE ON vw_movies_info FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE Function
>  iud_vw_movies_info_func();
> ```

**It is important to note that in our iud_vw_movies_info_func() function, we have the RETURN COALESCE(NEW,OLD).**

When I run the following insert sql code on the vw_movies_info  View :

> ```
>  Insert into vw_ movies_info(
>                       , name
>                       , director
>                       , cost
>                       , revenue)
>                Values( ‘Chronicles of Naria’
>                         ,  ‘Andrew Adamson’
>                       , 500000
>                       , 1000000 );
> ```

It is important to note that in our iud_vw_movies_info_func() function, we have the RETURN COALESCE(NEW,OLD).
When we running an insert sql code for a new movie entry, the NEW.id will **Not** contain the recently generated id value because it contains the NEW values that being inserted
Therefore, how do I go about ensuring that the recently generated id of the aforementioned insert sql code execution is returned?

Answer (score 0):

After the Insert sql code, I added  RETURNING id INTO NEW.ID;  , and it worked.

> ```
>   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iud_vw_movies_info_func() RETURNS TRIGGER
>
>   AS $$ BEGIN
>
>  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
> raise notice 'INSERT trigger, NEW = [%]', NEW;
>         Insert into movies(
>                   , name
>                   , director
>                   , cost
>                   , revenue)
>            Values( NEW.name
>                     , NEW.director
>                   , NEW.cost
>                   , NEW.revenue )
> ```

```
                RETURNING id INTO NEW.ID;
```

> ```
> ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' then 
> raise notice 'UPDATE trigger, OLD = [%], NEW = [%]', OLD, NEW;
>                         Update movies ee
>                                Set name = NEW.name
>                                               where ee.id = NEW.id; ELSE
> raise notice 'DELETE trigger, OLD = [%]', OLD;
>                         Delete from movies ee 
>                                   where ee.id = OLD.id; END IF; RETURN COALESCE(NEW,OLD); END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```